# Where does JavaFX create the FXML file by default?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

EDIT: Changed the question for clarity

Where do JavaFX application store the FXML by default? Do they create an FXML file, and where is it put if they do? Can I specify a place for the FXML to be compiled to? I'd like to edit the FXML directly, but I've written the GUI instructions into my main Java application (I'm a novice and this is just how I learned to do it). I'm using Eclipse, if that matters.

Comment: FXML files are not compiled. They are XML-formatted files that tell an `FXMLLoader` how to create the object graph. You write them, either manually or using a WYSIWYG editor (see [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/)), and save them as a resource of your application.

Comment: So what's going on behind the scenes when I write JavaFX instructions into my code? Does it stealthily create an FXML file containing the instructions?

Comment: No. When you create the scene graph in code you're doing just that—creating the scene graph in code. FXML files are an _alternative_ way to create the scene graph when used with an `FXMLLoader`. Using FXML files is a choice but they can often help separate the structure of the view from the programming logic. They're similar to XAML files in C#'s WPF or the XML layout files in Android.

Comment: For your information, FXML file is **not** required in order to write a JavaFX application. Have you written a FXML file for your JavaFX app? If yes, then you require a [FXML controller](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/fxml/javafx-fxml-controller-example/) class.

Comment: When a fxml file is parsed, a sequence of operations is executed to create objects/modify them using reflection. This means the situation is closer to "the other way round". The fxml is interpreted as java instructions (even though the result is not a `.class` file).

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX code does not generate FXML files. A hand-written JavaFX application will not use FXML and will not generate FXML. If you hand-write JavaFX code to define a scene graph then you are creating an object tree and this all stays in memory just like any other data held in objects (unless you go out of your way to write some object serialization process to write parts of your application state to disk).

FXML files are just XML documents which offer an alternative way to describe a scene graph. And the best way to edit FXML files is using [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) which is dedicated to this purpose. The idea is that this approach allows a non-developer to create and tweak the structure of a JavaFX scene, because you can use drag-and-drop and property navigators to quickly create any scene without writing a single line of code. Even as a developer I think that the FXML approach is far more elegant and faster than trying to write the scene graph code by hand.

It takes a bit of effort to grasp the FXML approach but I reckon it's worth the time if you're going to creating anything but the simplest scenes. I learned how to load FXML files into a JavaFX application from the book **Learn JavaFX 8** by Sharan, but you can probably gather the same knowledge from online tutorials such as [Oracle's Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html). (Be aware that the latest version of JavaFX is 12, but the advice about version 8 still largely applies.)